# How to overlay an oversize div on multiple table cell without using colspan

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have an oversize div displayed in multiple table cell.
Can't use colspan for some reason, tried `position: absolute;` but turns out a weird result.
Also tried to set `z-index: 0;` to cell and `z-index: 1;` to div, and it doesn't work.

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: #C2C2C2;
  border-radius: 7.5px;
}

.tmp {
  width: 250%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #34C6FF, #007EFA);
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing='10'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class='tmp'>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the css `calc` property (in addition to `position: absolute`) to accommodate for the `cell-spacing`.

Let's say `N` is the number of divs you want to hide with your overlay. The `calc` will have the following expression,

```
width: calc(N * 100% + (N-1) * 10px); 

/* so if you want to hide 3 blocks, your width will be */

width: calc(300% + 20px);
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: #C2C2C2;
  border-radius: 7.5px;
}

.pr {
  position: relative;
}

.tmp {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 7.5px;
  width: calc(300% + 20px);
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #34C6FF, #007EFA);
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing='10'>
  <tr>
    <td class="pr">
      <div class='tmp'>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```